# How can I save a typical startup workflow in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I find myself doing this often:

- launch emacs
- shh into a server by `C-x C-f [RET] /ssh:me@aserver.com:filetoedit.py [RET]`
- `C-x 2` to split windows
- `C-x o` to switch to top window
- `M-x shell` to start a shell on my ssh connection

I there a way to automatically replicate this process on startup? `M-x desktop-save` doesn't seem to be doing this for me.

Comment: Just define a macro for that. Then you can call them within just one command.

Answer (score 0):

Despite my enthusiasm for emacs, I recommend you to take a look at "tmux".

You run emacs in tmux only once. Later on, say when you are back in the office the next day, you simply re-attach to the tmux session and will find your emacs instance is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really specify a lot about your setup, and I agree tmux may help. In my case, I do a version of what you are asking about daily. I'm running GUI emacs 24 on my Mac, I'll be connected to work via VPN with several tramp buffers and shells open. Then I'll just sleep the Mac, commute to work, re-establish the VPN connection and then continue as if nothing happened with the tramp buffers, and after running M-x shell in the shell buffers, continuing as if nothing happened.

To repeat this for several file/shell pairs I would probably save the window config to a register with C-x r w X and C-x r j X for different values of X.